# Should I use .select or .each to sort array of hashes into 3 separate arrays? (Ruby)

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, optimization, micro-optimization

I have a single array of hashes that I want to sort into 3 separate arrays based on a value.

There are two obvious ways to do this.

```
arr1 = orig_array.select { |h| h[:category] == 1 }
arr2 = orig_array.select { |h| h[:category] == 2 }
arr3 = orig_array.select { |h| h[:category] == 3 }
```

or

```
arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = []

arr.each do |h|
  if h[:category] == 1
    arr1 << h
  elsif h[:category] == 2
    arr2 << h
  elsif h[:category] == 3
    arr3 << h
  end
end
```

Initially it seems like the second method, while more verbose, would be more performant because it only loops through the original array once. However, I was wondering if there might be some optimizations in the Ruby back end that would actually make the baked-in .select method faster and possibly more resource efficient even though algorithmically it's less efficient.

Any insights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try [`#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
orig_array.group_by { |h| h[:category] }
```

Which will return a hash where the keys are categories and the values are all the array elements with that category.

I agree that of the two methods you posted, the `#each` will be more efficient.